# Why my MsysGit bash can not use winmerge as difftool

Tags: git, bash, git-difftool

I tried to use winmerge as a difftool, but my git bash just can not use it.
I tried to use follow cmds.

```
git config --replace --global diff.tool winmerge
git config --replace --global difftool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
git config --replace --global difftool.prompt false
```

and tried to write .gitconfig file directly.
And I download the Git2.5 find out the winmerge file in mergetoo/,and copy it to my Git.
After set the PATH,`git difftool --tool-help`show as

```
    'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
                    vimdiff
                    vimdiff2
                    winmerge

    The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
                    araxis
                    bc3
                    codecompare
                    ...
```

Then I tried `git difftool`,the bash just use vimdiff,and I tried`git difftool -t winmerge(or WinMerge)`,the bash also use vimdiff actually.

---

My efforts seems has been effective. 
I uninstalled the git-for-windows 1.9.5 and installed the git-for-windows 2.4.5,then I copied the winmerge file from git-master.zip which was downloaded form github to my git's folder`../git-core/mergetool/`.And checked `$PATH`.
After those step, I typed `git config merge.tool winmerge`and`git config diff.tool winmerge`.
And `git mergetool` successfully started WinMerge, however `git difftool` still can not start WinMerge.

---

Thus my attempts are not single,so I don't know which operation is the key point.

Comment: How do you run git, from bash or `cmd.exe`? Can you start `winmerge` from that command-line?

Comment: From bash,and I can run winmerge from that command-line,but it can't run winmerge by git difftool